# SQLAlchemy Many to Many Understanding

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I just can not wrap my head around the Many to Many Relationships in (Flask-)SQLAlchemy or how backrefs seem to apply to my problem.

Heres what I want do achieve:

- n *Users* each have n (predefined) *Assignments* to do
- Each User can Submit their work (*Submission* - belonging to one of 8 *Assignment*s) multiple times.

Quick Example: Dummy User has 2 Assignments (e.g. Programm a For Loop), he/she submitted 2 code snippets (each graded individually) for the first assignment and none yet for the second.

So here is what I got so far in terms of Class Definition in SQLAlchemy:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    assignments = db.relationship(
        "Assignment", secondary="submissions", backref=db.backref("users", lazy=True)
    )


class Assignment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "assignments"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)



class Submission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "submissions"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    assignment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("assignments.id"))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref("submissions"))
    assignment = db.relationship(
        Assignment,
        backref=db.backref("submissions"),
    )
```

What I get is these warning so I think I am missing/not understanding something here:

- `relationship 'Assignment.submissions' will copy column assignments.id to column submissions.assignment_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Assignment.users' (copies assignments.id to submissions.assignment_id), 'User.assignments' (copies assignments.id to submissions.assignment_id).`
- `relationship 'Submission.user' will copy column users.id to column submissions.user_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Assignment.users' (copies users.id to submissions.user_id), 'User.assignments' (copies users.id to submissions.user_id)` etc.

Thanks in Advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read a warning section under the [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) documentation, which describes your case where you are building separate relationships (direct to/from the association table and a secondary).

Based on your model, I assume that the many-to-many will be read-only as it will not allow you to access attributes on the "Submission" anyways, and I would mark it as such:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    ...
    assignments = db.relationship(
        "Assignment",
        secondary="submissions",
        backref=db.backref("users", lazy=True, viewonly=True),
        viewonly=True,
    )
```

*Also [Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) might be useful.*

Comment: Thanks, somehow I was unable to find the documentation, you linked...